# Building bi directional theme + responsive theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to develop a web application, that should be bi directional theme**B** + responsive theme**R** I need a basic initial set up files(I mean adding base files like bootstrap , jquery etc). I understand that making bi-directional theme + responsive theme is in developer hand.I just need to know are there any bootstrap etc files that supports or meant for building bidirection/responsive approach. Also please suggest me any reference available for starting up **BR** applications.

regards,

Prad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bi-directional content is as simple as applying the dir (rtl or ltr) attribute to your page, then using bootstrap as usual. `<html dir="rtl">` will reverse the layout of the entire for you so as long as you use bootstrap classes properly and don't absolutely position elements, it will be taken care of. The tags can also be applied to specific elements on the page if you only want those rtl eg: `<div dir="ltr">`

Comment: How about responsive design?

Comment: That can be easily achieved using bootstrap v3, you might need to spend a while experimenting with their classes and reading their documentation, but anything you might want to accomplish can usually be done by adding some bootstrap classes.